# how do you get the author's username?

Tags: shortcode

how do you get the author's username?
I'm using this code
"get_the_author()"
I wanted to change this into author's username, instead of author's name.

Thankyou

Comment: Check out [get_the_author_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta)

Answer (score 5):

In the Loop, it would be:

```
$authorname = get_the_author_meta('user_nicename');
```

Or:

```
$authorname = get_the_author_meta('displayname');
```

Or:

```
$authorname = get_the_author_meta('nickname');
```

Or any field that [`get_the_author_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) accepts.

```
$authorname = get_the_author_meta('user_nicename',123);
```

If you just need to `echo` the name just use [`the_author_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta) instead:

```
the_author_meta('user_nicename',123);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding @s_ha_dum answer above, he is correct, but it's no longer `get_the_author_meta('displayname');`, it should be: `get_the_author_meta('display_name');`.

See:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/

Answer (score 1):

The actual answer to your question is:

```
get_the_author_meta('user_login');
```

Comment: This is the ONLY correct answer here. "user_login" is the "username" field. All the other answers have completely missed the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that is better help you.

We have multiple option to get author name provided by WP.
1)

```
<?php get_the_author_meta( $field, $userID ); ?> 
Via this function you can get current user auther name by:
<?php $auth_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' ); ?>
```

OR if you pass `$userID` as secont param then you can get that use field like:

```
<?php $auth_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $userID ); ?>
```

There is different fields that you can fetch via this function for respected author information:
`display_name`, `nickname`, `first_name`, `last_name` and [Many more](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/)

2. `<?php get_userdata($userID ); ?>`

This is done by setting up a variable called `$currauth` (Current Author). The usual way to do this is to put the following lines before the loop in your template file:

```
<?php
$currauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $_GET['author_name']) : get_userdata($_GET['author']);
?>
```

Or this example that only works in WordPress Version 2.8 and higher:

```
<?php
$currauth = (get_query_var('author_name')) ? get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name')) : get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));
?>
```

Now that you have the $currauth variable set up, you can use it to display all kinds of information about the author whose page is being displayed. Now you have below choice to use:

//For display name

```
$currauth->display_name;
```

//For First Name

```
$currauth->first_name
```

//For Last Name

```
$currauth->last_name
```

//For Nick Name

```
$currauth->nickname
```

and [Many more](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata)

Let me know if you face any further query regarding this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the Loop

```
$username=get_the_author_meta('user_nicename');
```

Outside of Loop (Suppose $user_id=1)

```
$username=get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename', $user_id );
```

You can use [get_userdata](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_userdata/) function.

```
$username=get_userdata($user_id)->user_nicename;
```

you can use [get_user_by](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) function

```
$username=get_user_by( 'id', $user_id )->user_nicename;
```